# How to rewrite PDF URLs to an intermediate tracking page before displaying

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite PDFs URLs to an intermediate html page using a parameter 'ref' set to the original PDF path. This intermediate page is an analytic tool used to track a PDF view. It uses JavaScript to record a view and then redirect back to the actual PDF source URL.

http://www.mydomain.com/dir/some-pdf.pdf should rewrite to: http://www.mydomain.com/elqNow/elqRedir.htm?ref=http(s)://www.mydomain.com/dir/some-pdf.pdf

Basically the rule needs to check for /elqNow/elqRedir.htm in %{REQUEST_URI}, %{HTTP_REFERER} and the 'ref' parameter needs to be the full path e.g http(s)*://%{HTTP_HOST}/PDF_URL (Can't figure out how to add http or https without hard coding it.)

Here's what I have so far, which creates a nasty loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/elqNow/elqRedir\.htm$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.pdf|PDF)$ elqNow/elqRedir.htm?ref=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Checking against referer to ensure it isn't the intermediate HTML page, prevents looping. Cleaned up the RewriteRule a bit to catch weirdly formatted "pdf" file extensions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !elqRedir\.htm
RewriteRule ^(.+\.[pP][dD][fF])$ /elqNow/elqRedir.htm?ref=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```